# Несогласный или не согласный?

Tags: частица-не

поддерживаем надежды, как мы думаем, нашего народа не согласного с этой политикой».   Как пишется в данном случае: не согласного

Answer (score 1):

**Выберем раздельное написание НЕ в обособленном обороте:** "...поддерживаем надежды, как мы думаем, нашего народа, **не согласного с этой политикой**".

**Встречаются обе формы написания**:

(1) Бедность содержания в «Мертвых душах» ― опять одно из тех суждений, искренность которых доказывается их невообразимою наивностью; замечаний, которые возбуждают жалость к сделавшему их и совершенно обезоруживает **несогласного с ним читателя** (Н. Г. Чернышевский).

(2)Генерал Лукомский выражал обыкновенно свой протест путем подачи записок, с изложением своего мнения, **не согласного с планом операции**. [А. И. Деникин. Очерки русской смуты. Том I. Крушение власти и армии (1921)]

**По основному правилу** наличие зависимых слов не определяет раздельное написание прилагательных с НЕ, что характерно для причастий. С другой стороны, прилагательное "несогласный" практически всегда имеет зависимые слова, и в правиле для этого случая делается **исключение.**

**Пример:** А) Шахматист играл **в несвойственном ему стиле** – слитное написание НЕ в утвердительной конструкции. Б) Это черты, **не свойственные нашей молодежи**  –  раздельное написание НЕ  **при обособлении (прилагательное по значению близко к причастию).**